# Error using the PWD to define variables in .gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I just noticed that when the `PWD` variable is accessed under `script`, it works as one would expect, for instance:

```
test:
    script:
    - docker run --rm -v $PWD/wd image [options]
```

**But** this fails when the above is replaced by a variable containing `$PWD`. In fact, an instruction like the following will result in an error:

```
variables:
    DOCKER_RUN: "docker run --rm -v $PWD:/wd"

test:
    script:
    - $DOCKER_RUN image [options]
```

This is because the variable `DOCKER_RUN` is being interpreted here as "docker run --rm -v :/wd". That is, like if `PWD` was empty, I cannot understand why.

I have also been exploring the gitlab [predefined variables](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) but cannot find a proper substitute for `PWD`, not by combining them, eg. using `"${CI_BUILDS_DIR}/${CI_PROJECT_NAMESPACE}"`, which also results in error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used `$CI_PROJECT_DIR`

```
...

test:
  stage: test
  variables:
    PYTHONPATH: "$CI_PROJECT_DIR"
  script: 
    - pytest test/integration
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try to use `$$PWD` when you define the variable instead. Then GitLab shouldn't try to interpret the variable, but instead just store a string `docker run --rm -v $PWD:/wd` in the variable `DOCKER_RUN`. As you have written it, GitLab tries to interpret the variable `$PWD` when parsing the .gitlab-ci.yml file. This is done on the git server, and the current working directory wouldn't make sense in this context.

When you use `$PWD` in a job, this is executed on a gitlab-runner as a normal shell script. Then the current working directory makes perfect sense!

Comment: After setting DOCKER_RUN: "docker run --rm -v $$PWD:/wd" I get the following error: `docker: Error response from daemon: create $PWD: "$PWD" includes invalid characters for a local volume name, only "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.-]" are allowed. If you intended to pass a host directory, use absolute path.`

Comment: Can you try to use `eval` at the beginning of the script line? `eval "$DOCKER_RUN image [options]"`.

Comment: No luck. It seems to be an open issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1809

Answer (score 2):

This trick [borrowed from a github issue seems to solve the issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4830#issuecomment-264366876):

> Ahh, late to the party, I searched, saw this, and realized if you want
> a "relative" path you can do this:
>
> ```bash
> docker run -v `pwd`/contrib:/tmp/contrib ...
> ```
>
> If you're running from a shell script, this is fine, you're going to
> be running it from somewhere, great for local development when you're
> standing up a few images and want to keep those folders handy.

So my command was:

```yaml
script:
- docker run --rm -t --env -v `pwd`/frontend:/app snyk/snyk:node
```

Which expanded `pwd` correctly.